# Caffe using hdf5 layer and imagedata input layer together in train_val.proto

Tags: matlab, input, hdf5, caffe, conv-neural-network

I am currently using hdf5 data layer for reading as input the images(around 30000) that I have and some metadata about the images.

I am unable to do the crop-flip data augmentation, as since when I just use the centre crops, storing data of about 1500 images only leads to around 1.5 GB h5 file, the total the size of the hdf5 dataset(30 h5 files) becomes ~40 GB, and so I can not use augmentation as then the hdf5 dataset would be too large.

So, I was thinking that if I could use the Imagedata layer for reading images and the hdf5 data layer for metadata, my problem can be solved. But I didn't find any material on this. Is it possible to do so?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it is, I thought I was getting an error but it was due to something else in my proto file, below is my input layers for proto

```
layer {
  type: "HDF5Data"
  name: "data"
  top: "Meta" 
  hdf5_data_param {
    source: "/path/to/train.txt"
    batch_size: 50
  }
  include { phase: TRAIN }
}
layer {
  name: "data"
  type: "ImageData"
  top: "X"
  top: "Labels"
  include {
    phase: TRAIN
  }
  transform_param {
    mirror: true
    crop_size: 227
    mean_file: "data/ilsvrc12/imagenet_mean.binaryproto"
  }
  image_data_param {
    source: "/path/to/train.txt"
    batch_size: 50
    new_height: 256
    new_width: 256
  }
}
layer {
  type: "HDF5Data"
  name: "data"
  top: "Meta" 
  hdf5_data_param {
    source: "/path/to/val.txt"
    batch_size: 50
  }
  include { phase: TEST }
}
layer {
  name: "data"
  type: "ImageData"
  top: "X"
  top: "Labels"
  include {
    phase: TEST
  }
  transform_param {
    mirror: false
    crop_size: 227
    mean_file: "data/ilsvrc12/imagenet_mean.binaryproto"
  }
  image_data_param {
    source: "/path/to/val.txt"
    batch_size: 50
    new_height: 256
    new_width: 256
  }
}
```

Comment: Are you sure your data and meta are in sync? I'm not 100% familiar with the mirroring options, but it might be the case you are consuming more meta than images?

Comment: I am not sure, how can I verfiy that?

Comment: you can create a dummy net with dummy data (including mirroring)  where the label of each input image equals the Meta of that image. Then you should have a loss layer comparing the label and the Meta. if they match: then you're good.

Comment: Can you explain that a bit more? What would the loss layer look like?

Comment: you can use euclidean loss layer

Comment: And one last thing is it normal that around 1500 images h5 file would become 1.5-2GB?

Comment: one image requires 256*256*3*4 bytes. 1500 images take quite a large disk space

Comment: I tried the dummy model, and the loss came out to be 0 everytime, so I suppose data and meta are in sync.

Comment: did you use the same transform param?

Comment: I also feel that they should not be in sync, being in sync seems serendipitous.

Answer (score 0):

I'm glad you [figured it out by yourself](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34819919/1714410). However, the file size limitation on HDF5 files is not an issue at all. In caffe, `"HDF5Data"` layer gets as an input a *text* file as `source` listing *as many* hdf5 files as you wish! Thus, if you encounter a large hdf5 file, you can split it into several smaller ones and list them all in the text file.

For example, you may have `/path/to/hdf5_list.txt` file listing the following files

> ```
> /path/to/not_too_large_file.h5
> /path/to/split_large_file_001.h5
> /path/to/split_large_file_002.h5
> /path/to/split_large_file_003.h5
> /path/to/split_large_file_004.h5
> ```

And so on...
Then your input layer would look like

```
layer {
  name: "input"
  type: "HDF5Data"
  top: "data"
  top: "label"
  hdf5_data_param {
    source: "/path/to/hdf5_list.txt"
  }
  include { phase: TRAIN }
}
```

Comment: You misunderstood me, the thing was a dataset of ~30000 images when converted to numerous small h5 files (25), occupied a total space of around 40 GB, and if I did any augmentation, it's size would increase probably by 10 times, as now for 1 images there would be 10 crops, and then the h5 files would in total be around 40*10 GB, the number of files was not the issue, but the total space occupied by them was.

Comment: And please take a look at this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34832161/caffe-doing-forward-pass-with-multiple-input-blobs) regarding forward pass for test in the above fine-tuned net. Thanks!

Comment: @Deven I do not work with the matcaffe interface. if you switch to python this would be a non-issue

Comment: The forward pass thing or h5 files thing?

Comment: @Deven the forward pass thingy

Comment: How do we do it in the pycaffe interface?

Comment: @Deven `net.forward_all(data=X, Meta=m)`, you simply name the inputs you provide according to the inputs the net expects.

Comment: That is cool, but I would first try an idea then see what to do next! Thanks!